# Сохранение видео из фотографий,python open cv

Tags: python, opencv, видео

Я провел алгоритм по выделению нужных фотографий из видео,теперь эти фотографии хочу загрузить в одно видео использую данный код,где он берет из файла все фотографии

```
 frameSize = (640, 480)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('I', '4', '2', '0'), 1, frameSize)
    for filename in glob.glob('C:\ Users \ CAD3 \ PycharmProjects \ untitled4 \ venv \ zoo-opencv*.jpg'):
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        out.write(img)
    out.release()
```

Вопрос,почему в итоге сохранятся видео маленького размера и которое не открывается?

Comment: Обратные слеши '\' в строках надо дублировать  '\\' или использовать raw-строки. Ну и нет там пробелов. 'C:\\Users\\CAD3\\PycharmProjects\\untitled4\\venv\\zoo-opencv*.jpg'

Comment: Все равно не помогает,я так понимаю функция glob glob ,не может найти указанный путь ,ибо если по одному фотографию вызывать то все спокойно работает

Comment: Если glob не может найти путь, значит вы его неправильно указали. Включите отладку.